# I would like to change page when the user scrolls down

Tags: vuejs2

```
  methods: {
    handleScroll () {
      window.onscroll = () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 0) {
          alert('toto');
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
```

This code does not work.
It is also triggered when the page loads.

Besides, I would like this code to be active only on the homepage.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello, your alert is triggered because your condition checks if scrollY is greater than zero. 
Try to increase this number, e.g. initial viewport height, ... or simply 100 eg. `(window.scrollY > 100)`, so you can check the result. Do you use vue-router?

Comment: Thank for your answer. In chrome or opera it's ok, but not in safari. And I don't understand why I have an alert box into another page too. And yes I use vue-router. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  methods: {
handleScroll () {
  window.onscroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 5 && this.$route.name ==="Accueil" ) {
      this.$router.push({name:'Offres'})
    }
  }
}
```

},

With this code, it's ok